# How to access my .txt fine in C# Form, I need first line of .txt file to print out on TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Sav1.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        richTextBox1.Items.Add(line);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

How to access my .txt fine in C# Form, I need first line of .txt file to print out on TextBox. This one is not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate more on the *not working* part? This is very ambiguous. What about it is not working? What is your current result and what is your desired result? Are you getting any error messages? To note: Your counter isn't currently doing anything other than incrementing. You can also use `while (!file.EndOfStream()) { } ` instead

Comment: What is this: `richTextBox1.Items.Add(line);`? It appears you're trying to add Items to a ListBox. You could just write `richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadLines("Sav1.txt").First();`. This if `Sav1.txt` is in the current working directory. Use full paths instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only wanting the first line:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Sav1.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

If you don't need the file for anything else, you can do this:

```
    string line;
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Sav1.txt"))
    {
        if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            richTextBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that either way, you should always `Dispose` of the `StreamReader` instance (easiest way is the `using` statement).

Comment: @Symon Point taken. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(here your file address + "\\filename.txt");
richTextBox1.Text = readText[0];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: no no i placed the index 0 it's mean only firt line will be picked up